# JQuery SYNC Ajax Calls in Firefox Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox, asynchronous

Well I made an Infinite scroll script, which is performing quite well. But just in Chrome and IE. Unfortunaly it doesn't perform the sync call on firefox but still hammers the server async... Meaning I get tons of content back which shouldn't have been requested... As I was googling around and didn't find a clear solution for my problem so I'll ask you guys:

```
var endajax = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (endajax == 0)
    {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 405) 
    {
            $('#profilecontent').prepend('<div class="iloader bgtrans padding ui-corner-all" style="position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 80px;"><div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all padding"><img width="8" src="images/loader.gif" alt="" /> Inhalt wird nachgeladen, bitte einen Moment gedulden</div></div>');
        var firstid = $('.postbox').last().attr('name');    
        var lastid = $('.postid').last().val(); 
        var data = "firstid="+firstid+"&lastid="+lastid+"&uid=<?php echo $profileuser->id; ?>"; 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.iloader').remove();
        }, 2000);
        $.ajax({
        url: "modules/users/profile/profileposts.php",
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: data,
            success: function(data){
                if (data.length != 2) {
                      $('#profileposts').append(data).fadeIn('slow');
                }
                else
                {
                    endajax = 1;
                }                           
            },
        });
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps lock your semaphore before the ajax call?

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 405) 
{
 endajax++;
```

and then

```
success: function(data){
            if (data.length != 2) {
                  endajax = 0;//or 1 depending on how you are locking this control out
                  $('#profileposts').append(data).fadeIn('slow');
            }
```

Comment: Nope doesn't change a thing unfortunaly...  But I gave it a thought and will probably try to solve it serversided as I am better with php anyways xD...

Comment: @IvanSchrecklich - Sorry that this isn't helpful. Good luck server side! :)